# Uploading files error with express-fileUpload

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

**I have an error uploading a file on the server if I can help**

This is a command to get the file from the client and save it to the uploads folder

```
exports.adminSendFile = (req, res) => {
if (req.files === null) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No file uploaded' });
}
const file = req.files.file;

file.mv(`${__dirname}/SERVER/Servises/uploads/${file.name}`, err => {
    console.log("****HERE*****");
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).send(err)
    }
    res.json({
        fileName: file.name,
        filePath: `/SERVER/Servises/uploads/${file.name}`
    })
    console.log(req.body),
        vacations.create({
            description: req.body.description,
            destination: req.body.destination,
            createdAt: req.body.createdAt,
            updatedAt: req.body.updatedAt,
            img: req.body.filePath,
            price: req.body.price,
        })

})
```

[Imge>>>Clike-Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P3Jm.jpg)

**You can see the Error here**

```
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Itzik\Desktop\לימודים\projact3\server\Servises\controller\SERVER\Servises\uploads\My Passport Photo.jpg']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path:
   'C:\\Users\\Itzik\\Desktop\\לימודים\\projact3\\server\\Servises\\controller\\SERVER\\Servises\\uploads\\My Passport Photo.jpg' }
POST /users/admin/upload 500 40.394 ms - 189
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`__dirname`** is the most common method. **It gives you the path of the currently running file.**

**As per your error , I think what path you are trying to get is this** :

```
C:\Users\Itzik\Desktop\לימודים\projact3\server\Servises\uploads\My Passport Photo.jpg'
```

**And not :**

```
C:\Users\Itzik\Desktop\לימודים\projact3\server\Servises\controller\SERVER\Servises\uploads\My Passport Photo.jpg'
```

You need to go one step up from current directory with `../` and then you are good to go, like this :

```
file.mv(`${__dirname}/../uploads/${file.name}`
```